# Ximea native c++ API vs opencv performance

Tags: c++, opencv, ximea

I would like to capture images with as little delay as possible from a Ximea camera. I see that there are many different APIs available, including an OpenCV plugin and a native C++ API.

I would like to know if there is any advantage in terms of performance of going with the native API. If anyone has compared them, I would like to know how much is this advantage